# How to create function that converts both List<List<Integer>> and List<List<Double>> (possibly more) to string?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

First of all, I know `List<List<*>>` has default `toString()` method. However, it only prints elements themselves without prints element count. My need is to print the count as well.

Suppose I only need to print `Integer` arrays, I can do as follows:

```
public static List<List<Integer>> fun() {
    ArrayList<List<Integer>> ret = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>(3);

    List<Integer> inner1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(1);
    inner1.add(11);
    List<Integer> inner2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(2);
    inner2.add(21);
    inner2.add(22);
    List<Integer> inner3 = new ArrayList<Integer>(3);
    inner3.add(31);
    inner3.add(32);
    inner3.add(33);
    ret.add(inner1);
    ret.add(inner2);
    ret.add(inner3);
    return ret;
}

public static String prtx(List<Integer> something) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(something.size() + ": {");
    for (int i = 0; i < something.size() - 1; i++) {
        sb.append(something.get(i) + ", ");
    }
    sb.append(something.get(something.size() - 1) + "}");
    return sb.toString();
}

public static String prt(List<List<Integer>> something) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(something.size() + ": {");
    for (int i = 0; i < something.size() - 1; i++) {
        sb.append(prtx(something.get(i)) + ", ");
    }
    sb.append(prtx(something.get(something.size() - 1)) + "}");
    return sb.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(prt(fun()));
    if (true) return;
}
```

The output is as I desired, which is:

```
3: {1: {11}, 2: {21, 22}, 3: {31, 32, 33}}
```

However, there are two problems:

1. I need to write functions in different names, i.e., `prt()` and `prtx()` in the example.
2. It only prints `Integer`, if I need to print `Double`, I need to write more functions. Things goes even worse when I have other type to print. This isn't neat.

At this moment, I need to print at least `Integer` and `Double` so I need a better solution.

Regarding to issue 1, I tried to give them the same function name, i.e., both called `prt`, it gives error.

Regarding to issue 2, if I name both function in different name (like above), but change parameter type from `Integer` to `Object`, calling `prt(fun())` gives error on argument type mismatch. Well, I could not cast `List<List<Integer>>` to `List<List<Object>>` anyway.

I hope if I can have a generic function that accepts both `List<List<Integer>>` and `List<List<Double>>`, or even better, more types.

I tried to do something like `if (something.get(0).getClass() == Integer.class)` but also doesn't work.

So please anyone could help me to get it correct? Thanks in advance!

**Update**

Thanks for all helpers! You're all awesome and very helpful!

Here is some of my initial thought, not sure if possible:

1. As `List<Object>` itself is an `Object`, so if I can declare a function like `func(List<Object> something)`, it should accept `Integer` List or `Double` List as the parameter, or a `List<Integer>` List as the parameter, or even `List<List<Integer>>` List as the parameter.
2. If so, I can write a recursive function that detects the type of `something` that if it's an `Object` then outputs its value, but if it's an `List<Object>` then call the function itself to unwrap the list. This will be helpful if my List has more than 2 layers.

A pseudocode would be something like:

```
public String func(List<Object> x) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (x.get(0).Class == List<Object>) {
        for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) {
            sb.append(func(x.get(i)));
        }
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++) {
            sb.append(x.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

This would be the neatest possible in my mind, but non of the answers so far do in this way, so I thought it seems not possible in Java :(

Comment: Have you tried using something like `List<List<? extends Number>>`?  And then use a `NumberFormat` to actually format the value to `String`?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I didn't, and not sure how to do it. Could you please give me some hints or links? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the signatures to

```
public static String prtx(List<?> something)

public static String prt(List<? extends List<?>> something)
```

and then it should all just work.

`List<?>` means a `List` of some unknown type, so it could be a `List<String>` or a `List<Integer>`.

`List<? extends List<?>>` means a `List` of some unknown subtype of `List<?>`, so it could be a `List<List<String>>` or a `List<List<Integer>>`.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know it's `?` in Java :-p. Anyway to make only one recursive function?

Comment: `?` is called a wildcard, and they're notoriously difficult to understand. I don't understand your comment. Are you saying you don't want a helper method?

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking about Template in C++ but didn't know how to do in Java. I was thinking if there is possible to make only one function to fulfill my need, instead currently I need prt and prtx two functions - maybe this is what you called helper method? Sorry for not been a native English speaker :(

Comment: It looks like chsdk has beaten me!

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you can change the requirements of your generics to capture a wider range of possibilities, for example...

```
public static String prtx(List<? extends Number> something) {
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(nf.format(something.size())).append(": {");
    for (int i = 0; i < something.size() - 1; i++) {
        sb.append(nf.format(something.get(i))).append(", ");
    }
    sb.append(nf.format(something.get(something.size() - 1))).append("}");
    return sb.toString();
}

public static String prt(List<? extends List<? extends Number>> something) {
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(nf.format(something.size())).append(": {");
    for (int i = 0; i < something.size() - 1; i++) {
        sb.append(prtx(something.get(i))).append(", ");
    }
    sb.append(prtx(something.get(something.size() - 1))).append("}");
    return sb.toString();
}
```

In this example, I've just used `NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();` as a generic formater, but you could also pass a `NumberFormat` to the methods to provide specific formatting requirements

As a runnable example

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        intTest();
        doubleTest();
    }

    public static void intTest() {
        List<List<Integer>> ret = new ArrayList<>(3);

        List<Integer> inner1 = new ArrayList<>(1);
        inner1.add(11);
        List<Integer> inner2 = new ArrayList<>(2);
        inner2.add(21);
        inner2.add(22);
        List<Integer> inner3 = new ArrayList<>(3);
        inner3.add(31);
        inner3.add(32);
        inner3.add(33);
        ret.add(inner1);
        ret.add(inner2);
        ret.add(inner3);

        System.out.println(prt(ret));
    }

    public static void doubleTest() {
        List<List<Double>> ret = new ArrayList<>(3);

        List<Double> inner1 = new ArrayList<>(1);
        inner1.add(11.2d);
        List<Double> inner2 = new ArrayList<>(2);
        inner2.add(21.5d);
        inner2.add(22.25d);
        List<Double> inner3 = new ArrayList<>(3);
        inner3.add(31.41d);
        inner3.add(32.0d);
        inner3.add(33d);
        ret.add(inner1);
        ret.add(inner2);
        ret.add(inner3);

        System.out.println(prt(ret));
    }

    public static String prtx(List<? extends Number> something) {
        NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(nf.format(something.size())).append(": {");
        for (int i = 0; i < something.size() - 1; i++) {
            sb.append(nf.format(something.get(i))).append(", ");
        }
        sb.append(nf.format(something.get(something.size() - 1))).append("}");
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static String prt(List<? extends List<? extends Number>> something) {
        NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(nf.format(something.size())).append(": {");
        for (int i = 0; i < something.size() - 1; i++) {
            sb.append(prtx(something.get(i))).append(", ");
        }
        sb.append(prtx(something.get(something.size() - 1))).append("}");
        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```

Which outputs...

```
3: {1: {11}, 2: {21, 22}, 3: {31, 32, 33}}
3: {1: {11.2}, 2: {21.5, 22.25}, 3: {31.41, 32, 33}}
```

Comment: I noticed you used `extends Number`, does that mean the `List` must be a numeric type? How about if it's a `List<String>`? Thanks.

Comment: In this example, yes, it must be a numerical type.  If you want `String` or other objects, then you need to widen the requirements (or remove them altogether), for example `List<List> something`

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do it in a single function:

```
public static String prt(List<? extends List<?>> something) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(something.size() + ": {");
    for (int i = 0; i < something.size(); i++) {
        List<?> subList = (List<?>) something.get(i);
        sb.append(subList.size() + ": {");
        for (int j = 0; j < subList.size() - 1; j++) {
             sb.append(subList.get(j) + ", ");
        }
        sb.append(subList.get(subList.size() - 1) + "}");
        //This is the test to add 
        if(i != something.size() - 1) {
             sb.append(", ");
        } else {
             sb.append(" }");
        }
    }
    //Removed the last line here
    return sb.toString();
}
```

1. Iterate over the list elements(sub lists).
2. Then iterate over the items of each subList and append them to the
   string builder.

**Note:**

For the generic type, using `Integer` or `Double` or anything else, you can use a wildcard `?` as stated by Paul or a generic type such as `List<E>` as the `E` is used for collections's elements, you can find more about it at **[Java Generic Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html)** .

Comment: It needs to be `List<? extends List<?>>` otherwise you won't be able to pass a variable of type `List<List<Integer>>`.

Comment: @PaulBoddington you are right, well pointed out! Thank you, I am updating it.

Comment: Thanks, but the line just before return outputs List<?> in original form - It would be worse to write another iteration inside for just this line :(

Comment: @TideGu yes you are right how could I miss that, You will not write another loop you just need to test if it's not the last element so you can append `;` after it, I am editing my answer.

Comment: PS, my initial attempt was assuming I can use some sort of `List<Object>`, and `List<Object>` itself is an `Object` so I was expecting if I can have a function `fun(List<Object> x)` accepts both `Integer` / `Double` and also `List<Integer>`, `List<Double` or even `List<List<Integer>>` etc, so I can test type of x in function to make recursive function. I'll update this thought in question if I haven't made myself clear.

Comment: @TideGu I edited my code to fix the last element problem. to answer your question AFAIK It's impossible to cast a `List<Integer>` to `Object`, I think for a safety purpose you should know the number of sub Lists in your initial list before casting it to Object.

Comment: @chsdk Thanks. How about using `E`? Will it make it possible?

Comment: @TideGu I think it's the same thing and you will have the same issue.